# Ятка чи торгівельна лавка, палатка?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, різниця-між-словами

Зустрічала різні назви місця, в якому продають певні предмети, речі, продукти: ятка, торгівельна лавка, палатка. Чи є якась відмінність між цими словами? Чи вони є взаємозамінними?

В [словнику української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/jatka):
Я́ТКА, и, жін.

1. Легка будівля для тимчасового користування (торгівлі, виставки і т. ін.); балаган.

Comment: Я так розумію, Вас цікавлять нюанси у вживанні цих слів (ятка, торгівельна лавка, палатка) — можливо, вони частково відрізняються значенням (не в кожному випадку доречні всі три), можливо, вони мають різну стилістику (частина з них застарілі, розмовні, підходять лише для поетичного стилю) тощо. Але @P.Vovk, по-моєму, має рацію, що варто явно означити, що саме шукаєте, прямо в запитанні.

Comment: Так, цікавить, чи є якась відмінність. Відредагувала запитання, дякую.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отже, мова йде про місця на ринках, де продають певні товари. Перевіряємо варіанти по черзі.

1. [Ятка](http://sum.in.ua/s/jatka):

> 1. Легка будівля для тимчасового користування (торгівлі, виставки і т. ін.); балаган.

Підходить під ваше визначення. Можна використовувати.

2. [Палатка](http://sum.in.ua/s/palatka):

> ПАЛА́ТКА, и, жін. Тимчасове, звичайно літнє приміщення, зроблене з цупкої непромокальної тканини, шкур і т. ін., що натягуються на каркас; намет.

Не підходить під ваше визначення. Водночас, за запитом "[торгівельна палатка](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%22)" саме у потрібному вами значенні є досить багато використань (900 результатів). Отже в розмові можна використовувати таке слово, але в офіційних документах або просто за потреби серйознішого тону краще обмежитися першим варіантом.

3. [Торгівельна лавка](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=46520&page=1468):

> Те саме, що крамни́ця.
>
> Мати все турбувалася, коли б його у лавку піти, набрати Галі на плаття (Панас Мирний); Хiба я якийсь крамар, що має лавку для сiм'ї? (В. Винниченко)

Отже лавка - це щось на кшталт магазину, крамниці, приміщення, де щось продається, а не просто великого намету. Є ще "[торгівельна лавка](https://www.google.com.ua/search?source=hp&ei=tsmoW6OYOJCSmgWEubHIBw&q=%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&oq=%22%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.35i39k1j0i67k1l2j0i10i67k1j0i131k1j0l2j0i67k1j0l2.1078.1987.0.2651.6.5.0.0.0.0.198.681.0j5.5.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.5.681.0...0.rxbstfpyiPo)", як ви правильно помітили у запитанні, але пошук вказує на те, що це словосполучення не надто вживане.

Тому, якщо вам йдеться про точність, то найкраще те значення, що вам потрібне, передає слово ятка. У звичайній розмові або у пості в соцмережі можна ще сказати "торгівельна палатка" або скоротити до "палатка", бо це слово широко вживане.

Answer (score 3):

> [РУНДУ́К](http://sum.in.ua/s/runduk), а, *чол*.
>
> 2. Легка споруда, що являє собою відкритий або критий прилавок для роздрібної торгівлі. *Пішла я в той ряд, де продають огородину. А ряд той довгий, похожий на вулицю: по обидва боки рундуки з покрівлею на стовпцях* (Нечуй-Левицький, III, 1956, 264); *Серед приватних крамничок і рундуків метушилися покупці та продавці* (Натан Рибак, Час, 1960, 156).
> 3. Невелика споруда для ремонту, лагодження чого-небудь (*перев*. взуття). *На розі вулиці моєї У голубому рундуку Працює швець* (Іван Нехода, Ми живемо.., 1960, 118).
>
> ---
>
> [Торговельна мережа](http://sum.in.ua/s/torghoveljnyj) — сукупність магазинів, *рундуків*, *палаток* і т. ін. у якійсь місцевості, у якомусь районі.